# Joint PDF of Brownian motion at different points in time

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be one-dimensional brownian motion, and let $s<t$ be fixed. I want to find the joint probability distribution of $B_s$ and $B_t$.

My work:

We know that $B_s \sim N(0,s)$ and $B_t|B_s = y \sim N(y, t-s)$. 
Therefore the joint PDF of $B_s$ and $B_t$ is 
$$f_{B_t, B_s}(x,y) = f_{B_t | B_s =y}(x) f_{B_s}(y)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}(t-s)}\exp\left[-\frac{x - y}{2(t-s)} \right]
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}s}\exp\left[-\frac{y}{2s} \right] $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi s(t-s)}\exp\left[-\frac{x - y}{2(t-s)} \right] $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi s(t-s)}\exp\left[-\frac{s(x-2y) +ty}{2s(t-s)} \right] $$

Is this correct? I thought it might be simpler. Thanks!

Comment: A more standard method: the joint distribution (and thus PDF) of two jointly Gaussian variables is determined by their mean and covariance.

Comment: The pdf of $B_t$ is $f(x)= (2 \pi t)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{2} \frac{x^2}{t} \right]$. You are a missing a square term in the numerator inside the exponential, additionally you have not applied the correct scaling to the variance.